# ADB doesnt recognize my device- LENOVO A60+ Android v2.3.6

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

Am using Windows 7 (64-bit) and Eclipse Release 4.2.0 to develop my android App.
I 've tried 
adb kill-server
adb start-server.Installed an USB driver from http://developer.lenovomm.com/developer/download.jsp and updated the driver.
But after checking the "USB DEBUGGING" in my device , its not visible in eclipse,i 've even tried checking "ALLOW MOCK LOCATIONS" option.
Are there any alternative ways to get it work ?

Comment: Check that the minSdklevel is that or owner than that of your device. Also make sure you're using the USB mode PTP.

Comment: can you see your phone in DeviceManager inside the category of Portable devices

Comment: yes , i can see my device in device manager under portable devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to device Manager and expand the portable device section. then you can see your device will appear there. then right click on it. select "Update Driver Software" then you will get an window. then Click "Browse My computer for Driver Software" then you will get another window with a link to your USB driver, if it is not there, browse file located at

> " \Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver"

click next and update the driver

then right click on the root element(Your pc name) and click on "Add legacy hardware" then you will get a new window. click next. then click on "install the hardware that i manually selected from the list" then click next. select "Android Device" and click next again. then select your phone manufacture and model. and click next and finish.

then unplug and re-connect your device to the machine. and it is good if you can re-start the machine. :)

In my case i have right click on "SW-PC04" which is my pc name. and select "add legacy hardware" and continue the rest as described above

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

can you see the difference between 1st image and the last. :)

Comment: yes , done that. It says "Windows has determined the driver software of your device is up to date" & Below that there is "WPD FileSystem Volume Driver".

Comment: can you see your mobile detected in androidDevice category in Device Manager

Comment: No. Its not in the list.

Comment: No not even then. There is no "Android Device" option !

Comment: go through the screenshots i have added.

Comment: pls see my screen shot

Comment: Thanks a lot for sparing yr valuable time Mr.Dehan Wijesekara. Those were very helpful. http://adbdriver.com/ installed this driver and now my device is visible.

Answer (score 8):

Try to with Adb driver universal from here http://adbdriver.com/

Comment: I can view my device in ECLIPSE :-)

Comment: I've been Battling with the Hudl 2 and an older Lenovo tablet and this fixed both of them!

Comment: Holy cow this is the one that's worked for me for my Lenovo A859! From almost 2 years later, thank you very much! Finally can use it for USB Debugging TvT

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@Dehan wijesekara Thanks a lot for yr screen shots . I 've added mine after following yr screen shots. Cant find in here too.